# tooltip in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip

Today I was trying to build a tooltip which will show below the mouse pointer and it move along with it. To do this I have written code below. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aminkodaganur/wqzcmzof/1/)

HTML:

```
<body bgcolor="#4679BD">
   <div class="pointer_tooltip"> 
      Hi am a crazy tooltip
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.pointer_tooltip{
   width : auto;
   height : auto;
   padding : 10px;
   border-radius : 5px;
   background-color : #fff;
   position: absolute;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).mousemove(function( event ) {
    var pageCoords = "( " + event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY + " )";     

    var position_top = event.pageY+18;
    var position_left = event.pageX-30;

    $('.pointer_tooltip').css('top',position_top+'px');
    $('.pointer_tooltip').css('left',position_left+'px');
});
```

This is working fine but whenever I move the pointer to left my tooltip his getting hide like below image

[image]

And whenever I move it  right its looks like this

[image]

What I want is whenever i move left or right the tooltip should move right and left respectively pixel by pixel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:-

```
$(document).mousemove(function( event ) {
    var pageCoords = "( " + event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY + " )";   

    //set the actuall width
    $('.pointer_tooltip').width($('.pointer_tooltip').width());
    var position_top = event.pageY+18;
    var position_left = event.pageX-60;          
    var width=$('body').width()-$('.pointer_tooltip').width();

    //check if left not minus
    if(position_left<0){
      position_left=10;
    }else if(position_left > width){
     position_left=width-10;
    }       


    $('.pointer_tooltip').css('top',position_top+'px');
    $('.pointer_tooltip').css('left',position_left+'px');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wqzcmzof/3/)